# Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field error while using spring rest template to fetch data from web service request

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Getting following error while using spring rest template to fetch data from web service request

> Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "SomeField" (class
>   sandbox.Stock), not marked as ignorable

Comment: you Java object model has some field which is not there in Json. And you hhave not enabled IgnoreUnknownProperties also

Comment: Show some code so we can understand your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has a field named `SomeField` which is not there in the POJO you're trying to map to. Alternatively, you can ignore the unknown property by 
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Foo {
    ...
}`

or if you dont want the exception to be thrown you can just ignore it by

```
MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

where MAPPER is an object of ObjectMapper.